# In R, take a date string and convert it to datetime format (using lubridate)

Tags: r, lubridate

In R I am trying to take a date string and convert it to date time format using lubridate but anm getting an error that:

```
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Using this code:

```
lubridate::as_date("1/2/34")
```

Shouldn't this just return a formated date time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.Date` or `as_Date` needs `format`.  By default, it can parse if the `format` is `%Y-%m-%d`.  Here, it is not the case.  So

```
lubridate::as_date("1/2/34", format ="%d/%m/%y")
```

Or more compactly

```
lubridate::dmy("1/2/34")
```

Based on the string, it is not clear whether it is day/month/year or month/day/year.  Also, for 2-digit year, there is an issue with prefix i.e. it can be either "19" or "20".  Here, it would parse at "2034"